How to use a PostgreSQL custom type as a nested POJO in jdbi?
I am trying to do something which I think should be relatively straight-forward with JDBI v3 (using the sql-object and postgres extensions).
I have an Item class:
public class Item {
    private String itemNumber;
    private Dimension3D dimensions;

    public Item(String itemNumber, Dimension3D dimensions) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public String getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public Dimension3D getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }
}

The Dimension3D class is:
public class Dimension3D {
    private BigDecimal width, length, height;
    private LengthUnit lengthUnit; // This is an enum, defaults to INCH.

    public Dimension3D(BigDecimal width, BigDecimal length, BigDecimal height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.unit = LengthUnit.INCH;
    }

    // Getters and setters.
}

I am using the following table schemas for items:
@SqlUpdate("""
        CREATE TABLE items  (
            item_number VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (item_number ~ '^[0-9]{6}[ab]?$'),
            dimensions dimension_3d NOT NULL DEFAULT (0, 0, 0, 'inch'),
        );
        """)
void createTable();

The dimension_3d type is created thusly:
@SqlScript("""
        CREATE TYPE spatial_unit AS ENUM ('inch', 'metric');
        
        CREATE TYPE dimension_3d AS (
            width numeric,
            length numeric,
            height numeric,
            unit spatial_unit
        );
        """)
void createTypes();

I am trying to make an insertItem method which takes an Item POJO:
@SqlUpdate("insert into items (item_number, dimensions) " +
        "values (:itemNumber, :dimensions)")
@RegisterColumnMapper(Dimension3DColumnMapper.class)
void insertItem(@BindBean Item item);

In order to try and make this work I have the above referenced Dimension3DColumnMapper (not sure that this is necessary):
public class Dimension3DColumnMapper implements ColumnMapper<Dimension3D> {
    @Override
    public Dimension3D map(ResultSet r, int columnNumber, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        return new Dimension3D(r.getBigDecimal("length"), r.getBigDecimal("width"), r.getBigDecimal("height"), LengthUnit.INCH);
    }
}

Finally I call these methods thusly:
@Test
public void testCreateTables(Jdbi jdbi) {
    jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());
    jdbi.installPlugin(new PostgresPlugin());
    jdbi.withHandle(handle -> {
        handle.registerArgument(new Dimension3DArgumentFactory());
        handle.configure(PostgresTypes.class, pt -> pt.registerCustomType(Dimension3DPGType.class, "dimension_3d"));
        handle.attach(ItemQueries.class).createTypes();
        handle.attach(ItemQueries.class).insertItem(new Item("00001", new Dimension3D(new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1"), LengthUnit.INCH));
    });
}

My attempt to make this work seamlessly has led me to register a custom ArgumentFactory defined thusly:
public class Dimension3DArgumentFactory extends AbstractArgumentFactory<Dimension3D> {

    public Dimension3DArgumentFactory() {
        super(Types.NUMERIC);
    }

    @Override
    protected Argument build(Dimension3D value, ConfigRegistry config) {
        return (position, statement, ctx) -> {
            statement.setBigDecimal(position, value.getLength());
            statement.setBigDecimal(position + 1, value.getWidth());
            statement.setBigDecimal(position + 2, value.getHeight());
        };
    }
}

I also tried to register the dimension_3d custom type (as seen above) which is:
public class Dimension3DPGType extends PGobject {
    private Dimension3D dimension3D;

    public Dimension3DPGType(BigDecimal length, BigDecimal width, BigDecimal height) {
        this();
        this.dimension3D = new Dimension3D(length, width, height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public Dimension3DPGType() {
        setType("dimension_3d");
    }

    public BigDecimal getWidth() {
        return dimension3D.getWidth();
    }

    public void setWidth(BigDecimal width) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(width, dimension3D.getLength(), dimension3D.getHeight(), LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public BigDecimal getLength() {
        return dimension3D.getLength();
    }

    public void setLength(BigDecimal length) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(getWidth(), length, dimension3D.getHeight(), LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public BigDecimal getHeight() {
        return dimension3D.getHeight();
    }

    public void setHeight(BigDecimal height) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(dimension3D.getWidth(), dimension3D.getLength(), height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return "(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        PGtokenizer t = new PGtokenizer(PGtokenizer.removePara(value), ',');

        BigDecimal length = new BigDecimal(t.getToken(0));
        BigDecimal width = new BigDecimal(t.getToken(1));
        BigDecimal height = new BigDecimal(t.getToken(2));
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(length, width, height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Dimension3DPGType that)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!super.equals(o)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(dimension3D, that.dimension3D);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return dimension3D.hashCode();
    }
}

I have tried this with/without the ColumnMapper, ArgumentFactory, and custom type registration.
The current exception I'm facing is:
[ERROR]   DatabaseTest.testCreateTables:21->lambda$testCreateTables$1:29 » UnableToExecuteStatement org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "dimensions" is of type dimension_3d but expression is of type numeric
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Attempting to correct this with using casts like below:
@SqlUpdate("insert into items (item_number, dimensions) " +
        "values (:itemNumber, CAST(:dimensions AS dimension_3d))")
@RegisterColumnMapper(Dimension3DColumnMapper.class)
void insertItem(@BindBean Item item);


then produces the exception:
DatabaseTest.testCreateTables:21->lambda$testCreateTables$1:29 » UnableToExecuteStatement org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type numeric to dimension_3d

For reference I am using the following dependency versions:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.47.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbi3-sqlobject</artifactId>
    <version>3.47.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbi3-postgres</artifactId>
    <version>3.47.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbi3-testing</artifactId>
    <version>3.47.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.softwareforge.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>pg-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Thanks very much for any assistance!
Update:
I tried the following:
package com.dow.inventory.db;

import com.dow.items.Dimension3D;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.AbstractArgumentFactory;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.Argument;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.config.ConfigRegistry;

import java.sql.Types;

public class Dimension3DArgumentFactory extends AbstractArgumentFactory<Dimension3D> {

    public Dimension3DArgumentFactory() {
        super(Types.OTHER);
    }

    @Override
    protected Argument build(Dimension3D value, ConfigRegistry config) {
        final Dimension3DPGType dimension3d = new Dimension3DPGType(value);
        return (i, p, cx) -> p.setObject(i, dimension3d, Types.OTHER);
    }
}

but this leads to:
UnableToExecuteStatement org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: malformed record literal: "(10.75,8.5,7.25)"
This String is coming from:
@Override
public String getValue() {
    return "(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + ")";
}

Don't know what the correct format is for this to work...
Update 2:
I think I'm getting closer with:
@Override
public String getValue() {
    return "(ROW(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + "))";
}

because this then leads to the exception for trying to "deserialize":
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToExecuteStatementException:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "ROW(10.75"
Don't know where this is coming from though because I use the following substring to set the value:
@Override
public void setValue(String value) {
    String[] parts = value.substring(5, value.length() - 2).split(",");

    BigDecimal width = new BigDecimal(parts[0]);
    BigDecimal length = new BigDecimal(parts[1]);
    BigDecimal height = new BigDecimal(parts[2]);

    dimension3D = new Dimension3D(width, length, height, LengthUnit.INCH);
}


I don't know why using just parentheses leads to a malformed record literal ERROR: malformed record literal: "(10.75,8.5,7.25)" as that it what is done here.
Update 3:
Seems like not including the length_unit doesn't work, this is now super close:
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return "(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + ",'inch')";
    }

but this yields:
UnableToExecuteStatement org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input value for enum spatial_unit: "'inch'"

Please provide the code part where you are calling insertItem and getting the exception.

Done. Sorry about that - had to edit stuff down from the actual code which has more fields and missed that line. Added the call to insertItem at the bottom of the test. The Item ctor just takes a String item number and a Dimension3D object.

Do you have a method Item.getDimensions()? Can you set a breakpoint to check if it is called properly.

It's just a simple getter:
public Dimension3D getDimensions() {
    return dimensions;
}

I can try and set a breakpoint but not sure if that will assist me too much.

I'm not familiar with jdbi but one thing that called my attention is that in your database the enum uses inch lower case and in your enum it will be converted to INCH uppercase in Java this makes a huge difference :)

I am not actually setting that field through JDBI because I am not passing in that argument. I am relying on the database to set the value to the default value which is inch DEFAULT (0, 0, 0, 'inch') - it's a sort of SQL "trick" where you can have a default value for an enum field. Just to be sure I did change it to INCH in the schema and the error is the same.

I can get a "better" exception by changing super(Types.NUMERIC); to ``super(Types.OTHER)`. I don't know what syntax JDBI/PGSQL is expecting in this case:
protected Argument build(Dimension3D value, ConfigRegistry config) {
    return (position, statement, ctx) -> {
        String dimensionValue = "ROW(" + value.getWidth() + ", " + value.getLength() + ", " + value.getHeight() + ")";
        statement.setObject(position, dimensionValue, Types.OTHER);
    };
}

Does not work.

I have figured this out.
Here's the PGObject implementation that makes this work:
package com.dow.inventory.db;

import com.dow.items.Dimension3D;
import com.dow.items.LengthUnit;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;
import org.postgresql.util.PGtokenizer;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Dimension3DPGType extends PGobject {
    private Dimension3D dimension3D;

    public Dimension3DPGType(BigDecimal length, BigDecimal width, BigDecimal height) {
        this();
        this.dimension3D = new Dimension3D(length, width, height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public Dimension3DPGType(Dimension3D dimension3D) {
        this();
        this.dimension3D = dimension3D;
    }

    public Dimension3DPGType(String value) {
        setValue(value);
    }

    public Dimension3DPGType() {
        setType("dimension_3d");
    }

    public BigDecimal getWidth() {
        return dimension3D.getWidth();
    }

    public void setWidth(BigDecimal width) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(width, dimension3D.getLength(), dimension3D.getHeight(), LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public BigDecimal getLength() {
        return dimension3D.getLength();
    }

    public void setLength(BigDecimal length) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(getWidth(), length, dimension3D.getHeight(), LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    public BigDecimal getHeight() {
        return dimension3D.getHeight();
    }

    public void setHeight(BigDecimal height) {
        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(dimension3D.getWidth(), dimension3D.getLength(), height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return "(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + ",\"inch\")";
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        String[] parts = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1).split(",");

        BigDecimal width = new BigDecimal(parts[0]);
        BigDecimal length = new BigDecimal(parts[1]);
        BigDecimal height = new BigDecimal(parts[2]);

        dimension3D = new Dimension3D(width, length, height, LengthUnit.INCH);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Dimension3DPGType that)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!super.equals(o)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(dimension3D, that.dimension3D);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return dimension3D.hashCode();
    }
}

With the following argument factory:

```java
public class Dimension3DArgumentFactory extends AbstractArgumentFactory<Dimension3D> {

    public Dimension3DArgumentFactory() {
        super(Types.OTHER);
    }

    @Override
    protected Argument build(Dimension3D value, ConfigRegistry config) {
        final Dimension3DPGType dimension3d = new Dimension3DPGType(value);
        return (i, p, cx) -> p.setObject(i, dimension3d, Types.OTHER);
    }
}


We then register this custom type on the `handle`:

```java
handle.configure(PostgresTypes.class, pt -> pt.registerCustomType(Dimension3DPGType.class, "dimension_3d"));

and our ItemQuery is successful:
@SqlUpdate("insert into items (item_number, dimensions) " +
        "values (:itemNumber, :dimensions)")
@RegisterArgumentFactory(Dimension3DArgumentFactory.class)
void insertItem(@BindBean Item item);

What's really cool is it seems like our default enum value trick does work because we can do the following:
@Override
public String getValue() {
    return "(" + getWidth() + "," + getLength() + "," + getHeight() + ",)";
}

and it will automatically set the value to inch.
